# keep table cell dimensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have set up a nice table with fixed height and weight like this:

```
<table border="1" bordercolor="#ccc" style="background-color:#FFFF" width="650" height="322" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="22">
    <tr>
        <td align="center"></td>
                <td align="center"></td>
                        <td align="center"></td>
                                <td align="center"></td>
                                        <td align="center"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"></td>
                <td align="center"></td>
                        <td align="center"></td>
                                <td align="center"></td>
                                        <td align="center"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"></td>
                <td align="center"></td>
                        <td align="center"></td>
                                <td align="center"></td>
                                        <td align="center"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So the cells (td) have a height and width of x and x (according to the height/width of the table)
The cells have pretty much the same dimensions. The problem is that whenever I put an img inside the cells they expand to adjust there dimensions for this. I put the img like this:

```
<td align="center"><img src=someimage.png></td>
```

What I want is to keep the dimensions of the cells whatever img I put in. So if the img is bigger than the cell it would keep its dimensions and the img would simply ''flow over'' the cell.
I would really prefer to do this with CSS, but if that is impossible than I whant to try Javascript (preferably Jquery).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always make them `background-images` of the `td`s they occupy.  They wouldn't *"flow over"* the cell borders.  (Not sure what that means.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a div with your fixed dimensions, and image has to be added inside it

```
<td align="center">
  <div><img src=someimage.png></div>
</td>
```

Comment: That does the same as the img. If the div is bigger than cell, the cell expands. Its a long story but its necessary to keep dimensions of the cell not rearrange dimensions with div's